# Android Layout MinWidth

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, css

I know I can set minWidth using xml but I want to know how to set it in code, because I'm adding Linear Layouts from code to View but when the content is too small all the layout's content I'm adding change and so, I need to set the minimun width from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `viewInstance.setMinimumWidth (int minWidth)`. you can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumWidth%28int%29)